# Compare round-trip list values and change them Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, swap

I have a df dataframe. The dataframe has three columns named "Source", "Destination" and "Path". The Path column is a list and the values ​​are the paths of various routers. The "Source" indicates the beginning of the path of the various routers and "Destination" indicates the end of the path of the various routers:

```
Source      Destination   Path
---------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------
10.0.13.100 10.0.14.100 ['10.0.1.26']
10.0.14.100 10.0.13.100 ['10.0.1.25']
10.0.13.100 10.0.12.100 ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.5', '10.0.1.2']
10.0.12.100 10.0.13.100 ['10.0.1.1', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18']
10.0.13.100 10.0.22.100 ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5']
10.0.22.100 10.0.13.100 ['10.0.2.6', '10.0.4.5', '10.0.1.13', '10.0.1.18']
10.0.11.100 10.0.13.100 ['10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18']
10.0.13.100 10.0.11.100 ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.5']
.....................................................................
```

What I would like to create is an additional column called "Path_Def" where the return paths of the Path column are evaluated referring to the Source and Destination columns.

Example:
I evaluate the origin -> 10.0.13.100 and destination -> 10.0.14.100 with path [....] and evaluate its inverse path or Origin -> 10.0.14.100 and Destination -> 10.0.13.100 with the its path [....].
What I would like to do is change the values ​​of the second path to those of the first path (always referring to the origin and the destination) by inverting those values.

So what you should do is like this for each value in the list:

```
  Source        Destination   Path
  10.0.13.100   10.0.22.100  ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5']
  10.0.22.100   10.0.13.100  ['10.0.2.5', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.1.17']
.............................................................................
```

..

The result I would like in the dataframe is like this:

```
Source      Destination   Path_Def                                      
10.0.13.100 10.0.14.100  ['10.0.1.26']                                
10.0.14.100 10.0.13.100  ['10.0.1.26']
10.0.13.100 10.0.12.100  ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.5', '10.0.1.2']
10.0.12.100 10.0.13.100  ['10.0.1.2', '10.0.1.5', '10.0.1.17']
10.0.13.100 10.0.22.100  ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5']
10.0.22.100 10.0.13.100  ['10.0.2.5', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.1.17']
10.0.11.100 10.0.13.100  ['10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18']
10.0.13.100 10.0.11.100  ['10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.6']
.....................................................................
```

How can this be done? I really don't know where to start and would be very grateful

**Edit** after @Simon code:

[image]

**Edit** Merge DF:

[image]

**Edit** after last code:

[image]

Comment: Are there any guarantees in row ordering? i.e. `10.0.14.100 10.0.13.100` always comes after `10.0.13.100 10.0.14.100`

Comment: No unfortunately they are scattered inside the dataframe for example 10.0.14.100 10.0.13.100 is in the seventh row of the dataframe, instead 10.0.13.100 10.0.14.100 is in the twelfth row of the dataframe

Comment: And so for the others, let's say that in this case I put them one under the other to better understand what I would like to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the dataframe to itself, and then applying a conditional and finally cleaning up the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup
source = ["10.0.14.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.12.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.22.100", "10.0.11.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.13.100"]
destination = ["10.0.13.100", "10.0.12.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.22.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.13.100", "10.0.11.100", "10.0.14.100"]
path = [['10.0.1.25'], ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.5', '10.0.1.2'], 
        ['10.0.1.1', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18'], ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5'], 
        ['10.0.2.6', '10.0.4.5', '10.0.1.13', '10.0.1.18'], ['10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18'], ['10.0.1.17', '10.0.1.5'], ['10.0.1.26']]

df = pd.DataFrame({"source":source, "destination":destination, "path":path})

# join column onto itself
df = df.merge(df, left_on=["destination", "source"], right_on=["source", "destination"])
# Conditionally choose the right path
df["Path_Def"] = np.where(df["source_x"] < df["destination_x"], df["path_x"], df["path_y"])
# Flip the ones that need to be flipped
df["Path_Def"] = [path[::-1] if source > destination else path for path, source, destination in zip(df["Path_Def"].values, df["source_x"].values, df["destination_x"].values)]


# select columns you want to keep
df = df[["source_x", "destination_x", "Path_Def"]]
print(df)
```

output:

```
      source_x destination_x                                    Path_Def
0  10.0.14.100   10.0.13.100                                 [10.0.1.26]
1  10.0.13.100   10.0.12.100             [10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.6, 10.0.1.1]
2  10.0.12.100   10.0.13.100             [10.0.1.1, 10.0.1.6, 10.0.1.18]
3  10.0.13.100   10.0.22.100  [10.0.1.17, 10.0.1.14, 10.0.4.6, 10.0.2.5]
4  10.0.22.100   10.0.13.100  [10.0.2.5, 10.0.4.6, 10.0.1.14, 10.0.1.17]
5  10.0.11.100   10.0.13.100                       [10.0.1.6, 10.0.1.18]
6  10.0.13.100   10.0.11.100                       [10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.6]
7  10.0.13.100   10.0.14.100                                 [10.0.1.26]
```

Comment: Simon I have inserted an image of what happened to me in excel format...

Comment: Anyway, Thanks so much for the help me

Comment: @LucaLazzati I don't think the conditional is wrong, maybe it is the merge. Can you show what the dataframe looks like after the merge?

Comment: Done, it's over

Comment: However it is very strange that it does so, can it be the quotation marks "" on the routes?

Comment: @LucaLazzati The merge appears to be correct, can you try running `df["Path_Def"] = np.where(df["source_x"] < df["destination_x"], df["path_x"], df["path_y"])`? You should see the correct paths assigned, but the list should not be flipped yet. Run it right after the merge.

Comment: I placed another photo above @Simon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228494/discussion-between-simon-and-luca-lazzati).